# Online Listing problem - Chat in php

Tags: php

I have to identify the online users

The condition is when a user close the window, he/she will be removed automatically from online list.

the List is being generated on the base of session value.

any one please help me.........

Comment: You can't reliably tell that the window has closed. You only know that the client has stopped sending you HTTP requests. How you want to deal with that is up to you, but you're going to implement some kind of timeout regardless of how you tackle it.

Answer (score 3):

its difficult to store a flag on the close window event. what if the user closes the browser of shuts down the system directly?

you can achieve approximately the same thing by storing a unix timestamp in the database every time the user does some activity (also including page refreshes ).

The to see whether the user is online, add a certain amount to time to this timestamp and compare the value with current time stamp.

For eg. lets say we decide to consider a user online if there is some activity in past 10 mins

```
$online = ($last_active_time + 600 > time()) ? True : False;
```

Comment: Lots of examples here, http://www.google.com.au/search?q=users+online+php+session

Comment: +1 This is a better idea and how most real chat scripts do it, with activity polling.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onclose = function()
{
    // use jquery to make an ajax post to your chats controller, telling it someone has signed off.
    // CURRENT_USER_ID will have to be passed from your application to JS, or you could try to read your session cookie there...maybe
    $.post('/chats/signed_off', {user_id: CURRENT_USER_ID});
}
</script>
```

That's the logic. The implementation will be specific to your application, which we don't know anything about.